# DTO of Typed Tuples

Tags: python, dto, typeddict

TL;DR - I would like to create a typed tuple DTO.
to avoid an x y question, the reason for that requirement is that I want to minimize data that I'm sending to save data (using a cellular modem), and so I don't want to send dictionary keys etc.
I have a device id. for each device, I have a list of indicator samples, each each has a time and value.
Eventually, the data sent should look like:

```
[<device_id:str>, [<indicator_id:str> , <value:str> , <time:float (epoch)> ... ] ...]
```

I want to create a DTO class to achieve this.
What I currently have is this:

```
class SampleContent(TypedDict):
    value: str
    time: float

class OutgoingSampleDto(TypedDict):
    indicator_id: str
    sample: SampleContent

class OutgoingSamplesBatchDto(TypedDict):
    device_id: str
    samples: List[OutgoingSampleDto]
```

To which I thought of adding something like :

```
def __repr__():
  return str(list(self.values()))
```

But this feels to me like excess work, that will hurt my performance in high data rates (i.e. creating a typed dict and converting it each time to my needed representation).
Is there any way that I'm missing to achieve my goal ? Or am I on the right path?